# Creating Free Torah Educational Tool Counting as Ma'aser?

Tags: halacha, torah-study, maaser-tithes

If I have an idea for a Talmud study aid, and I can't find such an aid online, and I pay someone to create it for myself, but I also put it up on the internet for anyone to use, does that count as tzedakah in some way?  Would it count for maasar kesafim?

(ie imagine I had the idea for the Gemara Card ([https://www.amazon.com/Gemara-Card-English-Hebrew/dp/1592644546](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1592644546)) and paid someone to create it, but gave it out for free.)

Answer (score 1):

The answer would seem to be "Yes, this could count as Ma'aser", as it seems to be similar to one who buys Seforim for public use. See for example [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 34:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.34.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) (emphasis my own):

> כַּמָּה יִתֵּן הָאָדָם צְדָקָה. שָׁנָה רִאשׁוֹנָה הַמַּעֲשֵׂר מִן
> הַקֶּרֶן. מִכָּאן וָאֵילַךְ יִתֵּן מַעֲשֵׂר מִן הָרֶוַח שֶׁהִרְוִיחַ
> כָּל שָׁנָה, [חוּץ מִצָּרְכֵי בֵּיתוֹ], זוֹ הִיא מִדָּה בֵּינוֹנִית.
> וּמִצְוָה מִן הַמֻּבְחָר שֶׁיִּתֵּן חֹמֶשׁ שָׁנָה רִאשׁוֹנָה מִן
> הַקֶּרֶן, וְאַחַר כָּךְ כָּל שָׁנָה חֹמֶשׁ מִן הָרֶוַח. וְאַל
> יְבַזְבֵּז אָדָם יוֹתֵר מִן הַחֹמֶשׁ, כְּדֵי שֶׁלֹּא יִצְטָרֵךְ הוּא
> אַחַר כָּךְ לַבְּרִיּוֹת. וְדַוְקָא כָּל יְמֵי חַיָּיו. אֲבָל
> בִּשְׁעַת מוֹת, יָכוֹל אָדָם לִתֵּן עַד שְׁלִישׁ רְכוּשׁוֹ צְדָקָה.
> אֵין לַעֲשׂוֹת מִמַּעֲשֵׂר שֶׁלּוֹ דְּבַר מִצְוָה, כְּגוֹן נֵרוֹת
> לְבֵית הַכְּנֶסֶת אוֹ שְׁאָר דְבָרִים לְמִצְוָה, רַק יִתְּנוּהוּ
> לַעֲנִיִּים. וְאִם נִזְדַּמְּנָה לוֹ מִצְוָה לִהְיוֹת בַּעַל בְּרִית,
> אוֹ לְהַכְנִיס חָתָן וְכַלָּה עֲנִיִּים לַחֻפָּה וְכַדּוֹמֶה **וְכֵן
> לִקְנֹת סְפָרִים לִלְמֹד בָּהֶם, וּלְהַשְׁאִילָן לַאֲחֵרִים לִלְמוֹד
> בָּהֶם, אִם לֹא הָיָה יְכֹלֶת בְּיָדוֹ, וְלֹא הָיָה עוֹשֶׂה אוֹתָהּ
> מִצְוָה מֵמָּמוֹן שֶׁלּוֹ, יָכוֹל לַעֲשׂוֹת מִמַּעֲשֵׂר.** אִם קוֹנֶה
> סְפָרִים מִמְּעוֹת מַעֲשֵׂר, צָרִיךְ לִזָּהֵר לְהַשְׁאִילָן
> לַאֲחֵרִים, אִם לֹא כַּאֲשֶׁר הוּא צָרִיךְ לָהֶם, אֲזַי הוּא קוֹדֵם.
> וְגַם יִזָּהֵר לִכְתּוֹב עֲלֵיהֶם שֶׁהֵם מִמְּעוֹת מַעֲשֵׂר, לְמַעַן
> לֹא יַחְזִיקוּ בָּהֶם בָּנָיו אַחֲרָיו (סִימָן רמ"ח).
>
> How much charity should you give? The first year you should give a
> tenth of the principle; and thereafter, you should give a tenth of the
> profits you earn each year, [after deducting your household
> expenses.]15 This is the medial way [of giving charity]. The
> commandment is fulfilled in its excellence when you give a fifth the
> first year from the principle, and every year after that a fifth of
> the profits. You should not give away more than a fifth, so that you
> will not become dependent on others.16 This rule applies only during
> your lifetime. But as a dying bequest, you are permitted to [donate]
> up to a third of your estate to charity. You may not use your ma'aseir
> [charity] funds for other mitzvah obligations, such as buying candles
> for the synagogue or other items used for a mitzvah, but you must give
> it to the poor. If you have the opportunity to perform a mitzvah to
> help in the circumcision of a child, or to marry off a poor bride and
> groom, or similar situations; **or to purchase Torah texts from which to
> study, and lend them to others for study; you may use the ma'aseir
> money if you would not be able to accomplish these deeds with your own
> money.** If you buy Torah texts from ma'aseir money, you must be sure to
> lend them to others; but if you need them yourself, than your needs
> come first. You should also be sure to inscribe in them that they are
> from ma'aseir money, so that possession is not taken of them by your
> children after you.

Comment: Thanks!  This does seem to be similar to "purchase Torah texts from which to study, and lend them to others," however it also says "**if** you would not be able to accomplish these deeds with your own money."  How important is this latter condition? What is the nature of this restriction, if it's a restriction? If I can afford it otherwise, I cannot count it? How would I calculate it?

Comment: @AMR these are all details you would need to go over with a rabbi